# Get video adapter that the monitor is plugged to

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, multiple-monitors

I'm having multiple monitors plugged to the machine: 2 of them are plugged to the external video adapter, 2 of them - to the internal videochip.
I need to know what monitors are plugged to external video adapter, how to find it out?

I've looked toward [EnumDisplayDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and I see that [DISPLAY_DEVICE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure has `DISPLAY_DEVICE_PRIMARY_DEVICE` flag, that can show me on what video-device is the primary screen. But it's not enough to solve the whole task.

**UPDATE:**

I've tried `EnumDisplayDevices` and in its `DISPLAY_DEVICE` object there is a field `DeviceString`.

```
DISPLAY_DEVICE DispDev; 
ZeroMemory(&DispDev, sizeof(DispDev));
DispDev.cb = sizeof(DispDev); 
DWORD nDeviceIndex = 0;
EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, nDeviceIndex, &DispDev, 0);

// DispDev.DeviceString now is what I need
```

It consists of the name of the video-adapter, for example `Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000`. 
But names can be different, how to separate integrated video and external video

Comment: This cannot be done in C++. What are your platform requirements?

Comment: Windows XP for now, only.

Comment: @IInspectable that makes no sense, the whole windows API can be called from C++ - or do you mean there are no functions to do what the OP asks?

Comment: I've added an update to my question. Getting the video adapter's name for each of monitor is possible. But there is no information about type of video-adapter (integral or external)

Comment: I believe there is no difference between external and internal video adapters for the OS, this is just a graphic device. And why does it matter for you?

Comment: @Andrey, I need to open a window exactly on the monitor of external video adapter.

Comment: Still dont understand the purpose of this. Why internal video cannot be used for your window? Maybe we are talking about primary/secondary monitors?

Comment: I need to open 2 windows on 2 monitors connected to external video adapter, not on internal. It because of fps of the process doing in those window

Comment: How we are closer to the solution ;) Rather then depend from internal/external definition (modern HD 4000 is faster then two years old entry level video card) you better check video cards capabilities and choose more powerful one to use. Check [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61938/how-to-check-if-user-has-integrated-graphics-card)

Comment: @Andrey, Now I look toward `wmic WIN32_VideoController's AdapterDACType` (it always returns `internal` for internal video-cards). But you advise to check video ram of every card? Or what do you mean by capabilities? internal may have more RAM, but be worse than external

Comment: Why don't you just memorize the window on which the user had the window open last time and open it there again? This way you don't need to fret about what window is connected to what. Let the user tell you.

Comment: Capabilities depends form your needs, I have no idea what you are showing. It could be hardware video decoding capability, number of texture units or simply RAM amount. But as RedX suggested better to let user decide

Comment: @RedX This assumes that the system's state will not change in between running the application. This is also the best way to increase the volume of support calls by customers explaining that while they can start the application, it shows up in the task bar, but no window is visible.

Comment: @Andrey, RedX. That's why I'm doing this. I'd like to automate the configuration of application (some windows must be opened on external video-adapter, other - on internal). I'd like to take this configuration from user.

Comment: @IInspectable Of course you check the current monitor coordinates when restoring. If they are not available you just center on main monitor. The user will expect some changes as he just removed a monitor.

Comment: @Andrey I did realize what you wanted to do. I just wanted to provide an idea of how to alternatively implement your feature.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of knowing what graphics card is internal or external as this concept is not present in windows. You could maybe infer it from the name but that would probably stop working with the next graphic card generation/naming scheme from the facturer.

The only thing you can do is present a list for the user with graphic cards and let them point to you which one they would like to have to application run on.

This also covers the case where the internal graphics card is better/faster/more suited for running the software.